# python merge row of text with same category

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm new to python can anyone help me with this.

For example, I have a data frame of

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,2,2,2,3], 'b': [12,22,23,34,44,55], 'c'['a','','','','c',''], 'd':['','b','b','a','a','']})
```

I want to sum a and ignore the different in b

```
data = ({'a':[1,2,3],'c':['a','c',''],'d':['b','baa','']})
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What you want is set. I don't know how to do it in pandas

Answer (score 0):

You Question is bit difficult to under stand but if I guess correctly, this can be solution.

```
data = {'a': [1,1,2,2,2,3], 'b': [12,22,23,34,44,55], 'c':['a','','','','c',''], 'd':['','b','b','a','a','']}

new_data = {k: list(set(v)) for k, v in data.items()}

{'a': [1, 2, 3],
 'b': [34, 12, 44, 55, 22, 23],
 'c': ['', 'a', 'c'],
 'd': ['', 'a', 'b']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `groupby` + `agg`

```
data.groupby('a').agg({'b':'sum','c' : lambda x : ''.join(x),'d' : lambda x : ''.join(x)}).reset_index()
Out[54]: 
   a    d  c    b
0  1    b  a   34
1  2  baa  c  101
2  3           55
```